# How to "create" HTML elements via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Perhaps there's a better way to word my question by saying "Dynamically create DOM elements via Javascript", but I decided to write the simple title in case the latter was wrong. Anyway, is there a way I can "spawn" HTML elements via Javascript? For example, I can click a button on my site, and a paragraph will appear?

Comment: Are you sure you can't see the search box at the page top right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement && https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `createElement()` like this:

```
var el = docment.createElement("elementtype");
```

This will create any element, if you replace `elementtype` with the type of element ("div", "p", etc.)

After that, you can use the native `.appendChild()` or `.insertBefore()` methods on whichever element you want to attach this new created element onto.

```
var attachTo = document.getElementById('appendToMe');
attachTo.appendChild(el);
```

And it'll be on the page after the last element inside of that element.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Comment: var el = document.createElement("elementtype");

Comment: There is no such thing as `prependChild()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
element.innerHTML = "Hey, this is a new paragraph!";
parentElement.appendChild(element);
```

For more information, refer to [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

Comment: Just a note: `innerHTML` is widely supported, but it isn't a w3c standard yet because it's part of HTML5 DOM, a Working Draft (however, it's a whatwg Living Standard). With current w3c standards, it should be `element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hey, this is a new paragraph!'));`

Comment: @Oriol That's one of the most trivial things I've ever heard. `innerHTML` is so widely supported that standards shouldn't even be a factor for something like this. I **agree** that `document.createTextNode` should be used for something like this example, and in most scenarios (although you could easily use `textContent`/`innerText`), but citing W3C isn't really applicable here

Comment: @Ian I just thought that if asker didn't know how to create an element, he wouldn't know that `innerHTML` isn't standard yet. And I think that, even if it's widely supported, everybody who use non-standard things should be aware of it.